# find the type of file from API response - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I have this code to download the file and save it but I don't know the type of the file so when saving it I am having trouble deciding the type.

**here is the code**

```
$tokenUrl = "/api/v1/gettoken"
$bodyData = @{
"roles"= @("CONSUMER.ALLFUNCTIONS")
"callingApplicationId"="IZGpLpXoN"
"applicationKey"="XpwR3ayFVtRCbIZGpLpXoNYdBfDQLUVb"
}| ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $bodyData 

$token = $response[0].token

$getDocumentUrl = "/api/v1/documents/single/65a6296932aab9ed621a29e1?requestedBy=1361"
$header = @{"token"=$token}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getDocumentUrl -Method Get -Headers $header -OutFile 
"C:\code\65a6296932aab9ed621a29e1.tif" #<-- here I need the file type
```

Comment: Are you hoping for the API to tell you ahead of time (so that you can pick an appropriate extension)? Or do you want to inspect the actual file contents after download?

Comment: the first one, is this possible? as I tried this in postman and postman save file dialog shows me the correct extension so I was thinking how can this be done as the file type is unknown to me

Comment: You're gonna have to tell us which API/platform/product you're using then :) FWIW Postman likely detects it from the mime type specified in the response header (or the content disposition header associated with the file contents in the response body)

Comment: this is an internal API product.. how do I check mime type or content disposition header in PowerShell?

Comment: A common option is to issue a HEAD requests ahead of the actual request to download the file, depends on whether the API supports it. But if it's your own API then you can do what you like - add a `/api/v1/document/filetype` endpoint for example :)

Comment: the API is internal but I don't own it so changes might not be possible :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

- Download to disk using a temporary filename

  - Use `-PassThru` to make the cmdlet return the HTTP response in addition to writing to file
- Inspect the `Content-Type` response header
- Rename downloaded file to the appropriate extension

```
# build mime mapping table
$mimeMap = @{}
Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ |Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -like '.*'} |ForEach-Object {
  # discover associated content type(s)
  ($key = $_).GetValueNames() -match 'Content ?Type' |ForEach-Object {
    $contentType = $key |Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name $_
    $mimeMap[$contentType] = $key.PSChildName
  }
}

#
# authenticate as normally here ...
#

# I'm assuming the real URL variables a absolute - we'll need it for the filename extraction trick below
$getDocumentUrl = "https://some.host.fqdn/api/v1/documents/single/65a6296932aab9ed621a29e1?requestedBy=1361"

# download to disk with basename grabbed from the URL and a temporary file extension 
$tmpFileName = '{0}.tmp' -f ([uri]$getDocumentUrl).Segments |Select-Object -Last 1
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $getDocumentUrl -Method Get -Headers $header -PassThru -OutFile $tmpFileName

# attempt to resolve file extension based on mime type
$mimeType = $response.Headers['Content-Type'] -split ';' |Select-Object -First 1
if ($mimeMap.ContainsKey($mimeType)) {
  # Rename the file
  Get-Item -LiteralPath $tmpFileName |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName,$mimeMap[$mimeType] -join '' }
}
else {
  Write-Warning "Could not resolve appropriate file extension based on MIME type '$mimeType' for file '$($tmpFileName)'"
}
```

This approach obviously relies on media types already registered in your Windows installation - in case you need to resolve file types not likely to be found registered on the machine that's going to be running the script, you can pre-seed the mapping table with your own custom mappings:

```
# build mime mapping table
$mimeMap = @{
  'image/rohits-custom-format' = '.rht'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77825848/45375):

***Assuming that*** the target web service specifies a **suggested output file name** in its **response header** via a **`Content-Disposition`** field  - which is ***not* guaranteed to be present** - you can examine it for the appropriate filename extension or even use it *directly* as the output file name:

- The **simplest solution** is to use **`curl.exe`** rather than `Invoke-RestMethod`, as it has an option to directly use the suggested file name:

  ```
  # Downloads to the suggested file name *if* specified in a 
  # Content-Disposition - if not, downloading fails.
  # Note that the use of the -d option implies -X POST, i.e. a POST request
  curl -w 'Downloading to: %{filename_effective}' -LOJ -H application/json -d $bodyData $tokenUrl
  ```

  - The `-w` argument prints the effective filename saved to locally; without it, you'd have to infer what file was just downloaded from examining the current folder for the most recently added file; while `-v` (`--verbose`) also contains this information (by virtue of printing the response headers), it's buried in a lot of additional information.
  - `-L` (`--location`) automatically follows redirections.
  - `-J` (`--remote-header-name`), which must be combined with `-O` (`--remote-name`) is what request use of the suggested file name.
  - `-H` (`--header`) specifies header fields, and `-d` (`--data`) a request body (which *implies* `-X POST` (`--request POST`)).
  - A **note** re [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **7.4+**:

    - v7.4.0 introduced support analogous to curl's `-O` (`--remote-name`) option *only*, albeit *slightly differently*:

      - You can now pass a *directory* path to the `-OutFile` parameter of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), and - as with `-O` - the *last URL segment* is used as the file name. However, unlike with `-O` - which takes the last segment of the *input* URL -  it is the *ultimate target URL's* last segment that is used, which makes a difference if *redirections* are involved.
    - Supporting the equivalent of the `-J` (`--remote-header-name`) option - i.e. automatic use of a suggested file name from the `Content-Disposition` header field - as well is *planned*, but not implemented yet as of v7.4.1.

      - See [GitHub PR #19007](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/19007).

**Otherwise**, the fact that you're using a `POST`-method request complicates matters:

- For `GET` requests, you could use `-HEAD` in order to retrieve the *headers only*, which would allow you to look for a suggested file name as follows:

  ```
  # Sample HEAD call with a URL whose response has a 'Content-Disposition'
  # header field with a 'filename' attribute.
  $url = 'https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse'
  # -> 'OpenJDK19U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_19.0.2_7.tar.gz'
  (Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head).Headers['Content-Disposition'] -replace '^.*\bfilename\*?="?([^;"]+)?.*', '$1'
  ```
- For `POST` requests, as in your case, [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77825848/45375) is probably your best bet.